# Correct Lagrangian for classical central force problem?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, reference-frames

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem#Lagrangian_mechanics) gives the following Lagrangian for central force problem:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac12 m \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2-V(r)$$

where $m$ is the mass of a smaller body orbiting around a stationary larger body. However, Taylor Classical Mechanics gives the different Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac12 \mu \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2-V(r)$$

where $\mu$ is reduced mass between two bodies. I don't understand which one is correct.

Comment: Both can be correct depending on how you want to model the problem. Note that $\mathbf{r}$ is *not the same position vector* in both of those cases. For the reduced mass case $$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_1} - \mathbf{r_2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite generally we can write
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac12 m_1 \dot{\mathbf{r}_1}^2+\frac12 m_2 \dot{\mathbf{r}_2}^2-V(r)$$
where $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_2} - \mathbf{r_1}$. Letting $\mathbf R$ denote the center of mass, i.e.
$$(m_1 + m_2)\mathbf  R = m_1 \mathbf r_1 + m_2 \mathbf r_2,$$
we can rewrite the Lagrangian as
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac12(m_1+m_2)\dot{\mathbf R}^2+\frac12 \mu \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2-V(r).$$
The first term is a function of $\dot{\mathbf R}$ only, and its only contribution to the solution is a uniform translation of the center of mass. The remaining terms are the more interesting ones governing the relative motion of the masses. Wikipedia likely implicitly assumes $m_1 \gg m_2$, in which case $\mu \approx m_2$.

Edit: Upon reading the beginning of the relevant section of the Wikipedia article, the problem it describes is "a single particle with mass $m$ moving in a potential field $U(r)$", so it is effectively assuming one of the masses is kept fixed. The Lagrangian above describes the problem in which both masses are free to move.